# Plot geom_area with no filling and colouring lines by variable/ or geom_line without variables overlapping

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-area

From what I can see, geom_area and geom_line plot variables differently so the area are on top of each other (they have different y-axis start) whereas geom_line they cross and overlap continuously. Do you know why is this?

I would like one of the following:

1. Using *geom_area* could I have no colour-filling for densities, and
   colour the lines selected variables based on “Case”?
2. Or could I use *geom_line*  like I have done but avoiding the crossing and overlapping of variables?

Thanks

```
dataA <- tibble::tibble(
          value = c(10,20,30,30,20,10,5,8,10,8,7,2,9,25,28,29,15,6),
        Sample = rep(c(1:6),3),
        Variable = rep(c(rep("C1",6),rep("C2",6),rep("C3",6))),
        Case = rep(c(rep("o",6), rep("a",6),rep("o",6))))
    #This is the geom_area graph
        p1 <- ggplot(dataA, aes(x=Sample, y=value, fill=Variable)) +
        geom_area(colour="black", size=.2, alpha=.8) +
          theme_bw()
    #This is the geom_line
        p2 <- ggplot(dataA, aes(x=Sample, y=value, color=Case, group = interaction(Variable,Case))) + 
          geom_line(colour="black") +
          geom_line(data=subset(dataA, Case == "o"), colour="green4", size=1.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `color` instead `fill` in `geom_area`

```r
library(ggplot2)
dataA <- tibble::tibble(
  value = c(10,20,30,30,20,10,5,8,10,8,7,2,9,25,28,29,15,6),
  Sample = rep(c(1:6),3),
  Variable = rep(c(rep("C1",6),rep("C2",6),rep("C3",6))),
  Case = rep(c(rep("o",6), rep("a",6),rep("o",6))))

ggplot(dataA, aes(x=Sample, y=value, group = interaction(Variable,Case))) +
  geom_area(aes(colour=Case), size=.2, alpha=.8, fill = NA) +
  theme_bw() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("o" = "green4", "a" = "red"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Is this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks @yang , but now could you choose a specific colour for a specific Variable? ie: "green4" for Case "o" ?

Comment: use `scale_color_manual` to set the color manually, see the answer above

Comment: Perfect! and if also changing the size of Case"o"? scale_linetype_manual or scale_size_manual ? I have tried in both but I guess I have the wrong code.

Comment: You need map a variable to size or linetype, then you can change it using `scale_*_manual()`.

Answer (score 1):

*Using `geom_area`*: use `group` instead of `fill`.

```r
ggplot(dataA, aes(x=Sample, y=value, group=Variable)) +
    geom_area(colour="black", size=.2, alpha=.8, fill="white") +
    theme_bw()
```

[image: plot using geom_area]

You can also change color of lines using `aes(color=Case)`

Comment: Thanks @ahmohamed , but now could you choose a specific colour for a specific Variable? ie: "green4" for Case "o" ?

Comment: Yes. using `scale_color_manual(values = c('black','green4')) `